# firewalld, only allowing SSH from specific IP which is part of a different zone

Tags: firewalld

My goal is to serve ldap to every client on 172.26.143.0/24 but SSH must only be available to 172.26.143.3. I have tried with the following:

```
# This is where eth0 is and no services/ports are assigned to this zone:
firewall-cmd --set-default-zone=drop
firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-source=172.26.143.0/24 --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-service=ldap --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-source=172.26.143.3 --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-service=ssh --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

With this configuration 172.26.143.3 cannot SSH to this host. Only if I add the ssh-service to zone=internal, which I do not want. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Sounds like you should move your trusted zone to a separate subnet. Then you’ll have an administrative subnet if you ever want more than one administrative PC instead of relying on a single magical IP address. This would also solve your immediate zoning problem.

Answer (score 1):

The specific answer is to create a rich-rule (a direct rule would work too I suppose) as they are both evaluated before sources and interfaces.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address=172.26.143.3 accept'
```

Why it doesn't work is because the source definitions in the internal and trusted zones overlap. This is a weakness/annoyance/bug(?) of firewalld where source overlaps are not really allowed. It works but it is dependent on the order firewalld evaluates the zones when there is an overlap like this. I haven't looked at the code but some explanations say when there is an overlap the zones are evaluated alphabetically and elsewhere it is based on the order the rules were defined. Either way, in your example, the internal zone is picking up the SSH traffic and dropping it.